# Is it important order of element declarations in layout-file?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activityLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ColorViewerActivity" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        // skip it
    </TabHost>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/decDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="222"
        android:textSize="19sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panelLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="1dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hexDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/decDescription"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/panelLayout"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:text="111"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I put the last `TextView (id=hexDescription)` before penult `LinearLayout (id=panelLayout)` I get the exception. From LogCat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{   com.gmail.leonidandand.colorviewer/com.gmail.leonidandand.colorviewer.ColorViewerActivity}:
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
```

What could be the problem?

Sorry for my English.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It does because you are indicating that it should be positioned relative to the `LinearLayout`. So you need to declare it after the elements that you want to position it to. If you aren't declaring

```
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/panelLayout"
```

in your hex `TextView` then it doesn't matter. This is because when its drawing the `layout` it sees that property and it can't find the `id` of which to position it relative to since it hasn't yet drawn that `view`

Answer (score 1):

try re-arranging the stuff below

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/decDescription"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/panelLayout"
android:layout_below="@android:id/tabhost"
```

The error might take place because you are aligning it in the bottom of decDescription AND below the tabhost

Answer (score 1):

Tabhost requires TabWidget with an id. This is what lint warned when i used your xml layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activityLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ColorViewerActivity" >
<TabHost 
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/decDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="222"
    android:textSize="19sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/panelLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="1dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hexDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/decDescription"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/panelLayout"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:text="111"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

TabHost has a tabWidget and a FrameLayout.

Snap shot captured from graphical layout

[image]

Working example at http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/